# Widget does not respond

Tags: android, android-widget

I have Widget that uses a service to update. It has a button on it to open the activity. It works perfectly. However, sometimes I click on the widget to open the activity and it won't work or update.

What kills an app widget? And if the widget is dead, why is it still showing on the screen? Is there a way to relive that specific widget without creating another?

Comment: If a widget is not responding anymore. Is it dead? Is there a way to relive it.

Comment: The service is stilling working and sending the updates to the widget. But the widget won't update. Unless i delete it, and enable another widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to include this code in my service class. Basically, it sends the update to every single widget. It’s been over a year now; the button on my widget always works and the widget updates without any problem.

```java
int[] arrayOfInt = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getBaseContext())
                     .getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(this, mywidget.class));

AppWidgetManager localAppWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);

new WebView().onUpdate(getBaseContext(), localAppWidgetManager, arrayOfInt);

int i = arrayOfInt.length;
for (int j = 0;; j++) {
    if (j >= i)
        return;
    int k = arrayOfInt[j];
    RemoteViews localRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(getBaseContext()
                                       .getPackageName(), R.layout.xx);
    localRemoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.tv, tv_text);

    localRemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(
        R.id.Button01,
        PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, new Intent(
            getBaseContext(), LicenseCheck.class), 1));
    localAppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(k, localRemoteViews);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Android will stop your  widget when it faces a low memory situation. 
Then it will restart your home widget after cleaning the RAM automatically. 
But this time, your home widget will get a different pid from the last one, 
so it cannot respond the broadcast.

[Updating app widget using AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476867/updating-app-widget-using-alarmmanager)

Comment: Thanks What i wanted to know. Thanks alot

Comment: So if the widget get a different pid. Is there any way to get that pid, so the broadcast will update the widget.