# Android widget not updating automatically

Tags: android, widget

I have a widget that works fine on Android 9. Recently, I got a new phone and it runs Android 12. I was testing my widget and for some reason, it does not update automatically after 30 mins. The widget loads fine, when I add it to the screen, but after that - nothing happens. It is a weather widget which should update every 30 mins (as it does on Android 9 device).

Any advice is appreciated.

I am using AlarmManager as follows:

```java
private PendingIntent createClockTickIntent(Context context) {
        Intent alarm = new Intent(context, StackWidgetProvider.class);
        alarm.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE); // Set appwidget update action
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

        ComponentName thisAppWidgetComponentName = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),getClass().getName());
        int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidgetComponentName);

        alarm.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                    0, alarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        }else {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                    0, alarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        }

        return pendingIntent;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        super.onEnabled(context);
        System.err.println("OnEnabled");
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1800000, createClockTickIntent(context));
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis() + 1000*1800, createClockTickIntent(context));
    }

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    System.err.println("Received intent " + intent);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(createClockTickIntent(context));

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);

    alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis() + 1000*1800, createClockTickIntent(context));
}
```

I also have the following in the manifest...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't always work that way, Use Alarm Manager to update manually.

- Link refers implement alarm manager width widget [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476867/updating-app-widget-using-alarmmanager/14319020#14319020)